# Solver Alternative with Nested For Loop

Tags: vba, excel, nested-loops, exit, rate

This is a reiteration of the previous problem I posted.

I restructured the code in such a way that I need not use the solver at all. I created a Nested For Loop and in the outside loop, I made the iteration my required variable, and the whole algorithm seemed to me much more simpler than using a solver, since I knew the minimum and maximum value the said variable could potentially take on.

I put a limiting condition on the loop exit, instead of an equality, since I realized that the value may never exactly be the same. Furthermore, I modified my original counter for the outer loop from a non integer value to its standard form, making the necessary changes within the loop.

I do not get a compiler error anymore, but my function output is saying that one of the arguments is not in the right data type. The sample data is as follows

I should be very grateful for any help in the matter. What am I doing wrong in this?

Test values (Zero_Curve is a sheet range set of values):

```
Clean_Price =  30,343,540
Number_of_Payments = 4
Coupon = 2.80%
Face = 30,000,000
Zero_Curve = [-0.35%   -0.28%   -0.14%   0.02%] (starting at index 1 for the code), with the output of the function close to 0.08%
```

Code:

```
Function ZS(Clean_Price As Double, Number_of_Payments As Integer, Coupon As Double, Face As Double, AccIn As Double, Zero_Curve As Range) As Variant
Dim j As Integer
For j = 0 To 2000 Step 1
Dim SP As Double
Dim i As Integer
For i = 0 To Number_of_Payments
   Dim Payment() As Double
   ReDim Payment(0 To Number_of_Payments) As Double
   Dim Disc() As Double
   ReDim Disc(0 To Number_of_Payments) As Double
   Dim Discp() As Double
   ReDim Discp(0 To Number_of_Payments)
   Select Case i

   Case 0
   Payment(i) = AccIn
   Disc(i) = 1
   Discp(i) = Payment(i) * Disc(i)

   Case Number_of_Payments - 1
   Payment(i) = (AccIn / Coupon) + (Coupon * Face)
   Disc(i) = 1 / (1 + Zero_Curve(i) + ((j - 1000) / 10000)) ^ i
   Discp(i) = Payment(i) * Disc(i)

   Case Number_of_Payments
   Payment(i) = ((Coupon * Face) - (AccIn)) + (((Coupon * Face) - (AccIn)) / Coupon)
   Disc(i) = 1 / (1 + Zero_Curve(i) + ((j - 1000) / 10000)) ^ i
   Discp(i) = Payment(i) * Disc(i)

   Case Else
   Payment(i) = Coupon * Face
   Disc(i) = 1 / (1 + Zero_Curve(i) + ((j - 1000) / 10000)) ^ i
   Discp(i) = Payment(i) * Disc(i)
End Select
Next i
SP = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Discp())
If Abs((SP / (Clean_Price + AccIn)) - 1) < 0.00001 Then Exit For
Next j
ZS = (j - 1000) / 10000

End Function
```

Comment: Hello QHarr. My mistake with the value of AccIn. It is 51,407. And indeed, Zero_Curve is supposed to be a range selection from the sheet. I seem to have made all the declarations. Could you point out the one that I missed?

Comment: Thank you QHarr! As per your suggestion, I changed the variable types to double wherever I did not need Integers and corrected the Clean_Price6, which was just a typo. Furthermore, the error was coming because of the Zero_Curve case number 0. There was no value there, and hence I changed the value Disc(1) into 1. I have started getting numbers now, but I am still off. For some reason, my original condition

Comment: I would [edit] your question to reflect the current code and situation. Try to avoid large blocks of unbroken question text and instead split out into paragraphs so easier to read.

Comment: ...exit condition does not seem to execute and I get the function value which simply overflow the outer FOR loop. I am working on it, and hopefully, it will soon be resolved:-)

Comment: I realise that now. I am still new to this platform, and I am learning new things every time I come on here.

Comment: that's not a problem :-) I am gonna tidy up some of my comments. Step through your code with F8 and find where the flow diverts from what you expected then check the logic at that point is correct and values are as expected for variables.